# invoking a cgi script from within an HTML file (on localhost)

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I'm starting out with CGI programming and have a question regarding the security aspect of  invoking a CGI script from within an index file. Here's the simple CGI-script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

And here's what the index file looks like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py">HELLO</a>
```

Note that I've called the cgi script using the full URL - `http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py`

My local Apache web server configuration for CGI is like so:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This script works as expected at the moment, such that when the "Hello" link is clicked, the output of the CGI script is displayed. I have 2 questions related to this:

- Is this method of calling CGI scripts correct, since this will pretty much be a site that has various CGI scripts that run different tasks and in all probability will be invoked via buttons or links?
- I do not know if I'm asking this question in the proper manner, but is it possible to not show the destination URL? At the moment, `localhost/whoisit/` shows the Hyperlink and clicking on the link called "Hello" shows the following URL in the address bar - `localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, please, if you're just learning web programming *don't* do CGI. There's no point: it's an outdated technology that doesn't scale, and there are far better ways to do websites with Python (ie use a WSGI framework).

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Thank you for your quick response, Sir. Are links such as these a good starting points? 
[ivory.idyll.org's articles](http://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) and [fullstackpython](http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/wsgi-intro/what-is-wsgi.html) ?
Furthermore, can this be used on shared server platforms wherein root access isn't available to modify/configure `httpd.conf`?

Comment: That's probably a bit low-level if you're just starting out. I'd suggest learning a framework such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) - they both have great tutorials that should get you up and running quickly. And there are plenty of shared server providers that allow you to configure WSGI, such as Webfaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) yes, it is the correct method to invoke the CGI script.

b) To, hide the details in the URL, you need to learn about `URL rewriting`. Google it and you will find many tutorials and websites which will teach you this. There are also websites which generate the code for URL rewriting if you give them your original URL. You can just copy-paste that code in the appropriate file as per your server (e.g. `.htaccess` for apache server).